# C# Label Printer printing probem and Driver access

Tags: c#, printing, driver

I am trying to print on labels that are 2 in a row and X in columns (The user can say how many), each label need to have a unique serial number (So no Copies Allowed).

the printer's original app is bartender (TTP-244 printer pro/plus)

i must mention after each print, the printer starts adjusting the paper since there are gaps between labels.

when I use bartender app and print 100 labels, the printer does it fast ()seems like there is no adjust in between each label being printed), however in my code each time (sometimes even up to 5 prints in a row) printer start adjusting the paper (the paper goes back into printer like 5 millimeters and then comes out again) so it becomes very slow and noisy.

I must mention if i print the same label and use the number of copies = 100 in my app , everything is ok but its copy ! so the erial numbers are the same, I need to change serial numbers after each print.

```
    PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();

    private void button_setting_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        doc.PrintPage += Doc_PrintPage;
        print.Document = doc;
        if (print.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            print.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1;
    /*set the copy to 1 _ for each label there is a need for new Serial number , and the quantity of Serial number is set in C# app*/
        }
    }
private void button_printLable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           int numberOfCopiestemp = numberOfCopies;
           print.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1;

            while (numberOfCopies > 0)
            {
                doc.Print();
                numberOfCopies--;
            }
            numberOfCopies = numberOfCopiestemp;
    }
    private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // float x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        // float y = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        /* */

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(selectedCar.imageAddress);
        float tgtWidthMM = selectedCar.printWidthmm;
        float tgtHeightMM = selectedCar.printHeightmm;
        float tgtWidthInches = tgtWidthMM / 25.4f;
        float tgtHeightInches = tgtHeightMM / 25.4f;
        float srcWidthPx = bmp.Width;
        float srcHeightPx = bmp.Height;
        float dpiX = srcWidthPx / tgtWidthInches;
        float dpiY = srcHeightPx / tgtHeightInches;
        bmp.SetResolution(dpiX, dpiY);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)bmp, selectedCar.printStartX, selectedCar.printStartY);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)bmp, selectedCar.printStartX + selectedCar.printGap, selectedCar.printStartY); 

        bmp.Dispose();
    }
```

i just want to mention that i am sending bitmap to printer while i guess bartender uses XPML .
when i click and save to file while printing , bartender gives me this file (which seems to be the commands for printing ):

```
<xpml><page quantity='0' pitch='22.3 mm'></xpml>SIZE 82.1 mm, 22.3 mm
GAP 1.8 mm, 0 mm
SPEED 4
DENSITY 7
SET RIBBON ON
DIRECTION 0,0
REFERENCE 0,0
OFFSET 0 mm
SET TEAR OFF
SET PEEL OFF
SET CUTTER OFF
SET PARTIAL_CUTTER OFF
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='0' pitch='22.3 mm'></xpml>DOWNLOAD "LOGO_0.PCX",1046,
/* here was 3000 byte of data*/
DOWNLOAD "FORM_0.BAS"
PUTPCX 149,145,"LOGO_0.PCX"
CODEPAGE 1252
TEXT 642,140,"0",180,7,6," PARS ATC CCU"
TEXT 646,119,"0",180,9,5,"R1586-10300"
TEXT 646,102,"0",180,6,6,"S/N:02/04/29-"
BOX 360,86,444,128,1
BAR 360,107, 84, 2
TEXT 442,125,"0",180,5,6,"HW  Rev   01"
TEXT 442,103,"0",180,6,6,"SW Rev   03"
BOX 372,139,466,166,3
BAR 343,76, 312, 3
TEXT 642,73,"0",180,7,7,"PAYDAR ANDISHAN DANA CO."
TEXT 455,161,"0",180,11,6," PAD"
TEXT 546,102,"0",180,6,7,AA$
TEXT 309,140,"0",180,7,6," PARS ATC CCU"
TEXT 313,119,"0",180,9,5,"R1586-10300"
TEXT 313,102,"0",180,6,6,"S/N:02/04/29-"
BOX 27,86,111,128,1
BAR 27,107, 84, 2
TEXT 109,125,"0",180,5,6,"HW  Rev   01"
TEXT 109,103,"0",180,6,6,"SW Rev   03"
BOX 39,139,133,166,3
BAR 10,76, 312, 3
TEXT 309,73,"0",180,7,7,"PAYDAR ANDISHAN DANA CO."
TEXT 122,161,"0",180,11,6," PAD"
TEXT 213,102,"0",180,6,7,AB$
EOP
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='1' pitch='22.3 mm'></xpml>AA$="1130018003"
AB$="1130018004"
SIZE 82.1 mm, 22.3 mm
GAP 1.8 mm, 0 mm
CLS
RUN "FORM_0.BAS"
PRINT 1,1
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='1' pitch='22.3 mm'></xpml>AA$="1130018005"
AB$="1130018006"
CLS
RUN "FORM_0.BAS"
PRINT 1,1
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='1' pitch='22.3 mm'></xpml>AA$="1130018007"
AB$="1130018008"
CLS
RUN "FORM_0.BAS"
PRINT 1,1
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='1' pitch='22.3 mm'></xpml>AA$="1130018009"
AB$="1130018010"
CLS
RUN "FORM_0.BAS"
PRINT 1,1
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='1' pitch='22.3 mm'></xpml>AA$="1130018011"
AB$="1130018012"
CLS
RUN "FORM_0.BAS"
PRINT 1,1
<xpml></page></xpml>KILL "FORM_0.BAS"
KILL "LOGO_0.PCX"
<xpml><end/></xpml>
```

at the beginning of the file, there are some Commands.

so now my question :
1- can my program in C# be fixed? so it will print without a problem?
2- if not , then how can I send commands by C# to the printer via Driver? (i have worked with serial port AT commands and network byt this is USB ) it seems bartender is sending quite a number of setting which is not available to me .